# Create multiple dataframes and add a column to them within a loop

Tags: r

I'd like to create multiple data frames with a for loop, and add a column and remove others from each of the new data frames.  The original dataset looks something like this:

```
Site  Count1  Count2  Count3  Count4  Count5  Count6  Count7  Count8  Count9  Habitat
  1     0       0       0       0       1       0        2       0       1     Forest
  2     1       2       3       0       0       2        0       1       0     Field
  3     2       0       0       1       1       1        0       2       0     Field
```

Essentially I want to create a new data frame for each count column, so here I would have nine new dataframes that look like this:

df.1:

```
Site TotCount Habitat
  1     0       Forest
  2     1       Field
  3     2       Field
```

df.2:

```
Site TotCount Habitat
  1     0       Forest
  2     2       Field
  3     0       Field
```

And so on.

This creates the frames I need:

```
for (z in 1:9){       
  assign(paste("df",z,sep="."),orig_data)
}
```

I can't figure out the second step - carry the appropriate count into each new data frame along with the habitat column (and others not shown above).  I am hoping to keep this automated as it's possible there could be many more than 9 counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will create a list of nine data.frames which is (trust me) a much better thing than creating nine variables into your global environment:

```
data.list <- lapply(1:9, function(i) {
  setNames(data[c("Site", paste0("Count", i), "Habitat")],
           c("Site", "TotCount", "Habitat"))
})
```

Instead of `df.1`, you can access the first data.frame by doing `data.list[[1]]`. Also, if you want to apply a function to all data.frames (i.e. a loop), have a look at `lapply` or `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

This will put the `df.x` objects into the global environment.

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(Site = 1:3, 
                 Count1 = 0:2, 
                 Count2 = c(0,2,0), 
                 Count3 = c(0,3,0), 
                 Habitat = c("Forest", "Field", "Field") 
                 )
```

A function to do the work:

```
countSplit_2df <- function(DF){
    CountCols <- grep("Count", names(DF))
    HabCol <- grep("Habitat", names(DF))
    for (z in CountCols) {
        assign(paste("df", z, sep="."), 
               rbind(df[,c(1, z, HabCol)]),
               envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}
```

Now apply it:

```
countSplit_2df(df)
```

And `ls()` and you'll see

```
> ls()
[1] "countSplit_2df" "df"             "df.2"           "df.3"          
[5] "df.4"
```

Note this is not *exactly* as you asked for, as i've named them using the column number from the `grep`.

To complete the answer, someone needs to get the right way of selecting the text after "Count" in the `grep` -- you'd then use that to label the `df.x` objects. I couldn't get it to work.